# C++ adding extra, unwanted characters to a string

Tags: c++, string

I am having a bug that I cannot find a fix for through google searching. I am attempting to make a text based version of the game Mastermind. I am using a string the is set from an array of chars as the criteria for a `while` loop. When the string is equal to "****" the game is supposed to tell the player that they won and exit, but for some reason a ^A is being added on to the end of the string that is being checked, even though it is not in the char array.

Here is the function that sets the char array and returns a string from that array:

```
string check(int guess[4], int num[4]) {

    char hints[4];

    cout << "        ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        if (guess[i] == num[i]) {

            hints[i] = '*';
            cout << "*";

        }
        else {

            for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {

                if (guess[i] == num[x]) {

                    cout << "+";

                }

            }
        }

        if (guess[i] != num[i]) {

            hints[i] = ' ';

        }

    }

    string hint(hints);

    cout << endl;
    cout << hint << endl;

    return hint;

}
```

And here is the function checking the value of the string:

```
while (hints.compare("****") != 0) {

        if (guessCount == 5) {

            break;

        }

        cout << "Guess?: ";
        cin >> guess;

        intToArray(guess, guessArr);

        hints = check(guessArr, nums);

        cout << hints << endl;

        guessCount++;

    }

    if (hints.compare("****") == 0) {

        cout << "You win! The number was: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            cout << nums[i];

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't null-terminated the `hints` array, so you are getting extra garbage that is lying around on the stack in your string.

You could let the `hint` string know how long it is when you are constructing it.

```
string hint(hints, 4);

cout << endl;
cout << hint << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, sadly I have turned my computer off for the night so I can't test if that fixes the problem until the morning, but I will try it as soon as I get the chance and let you know if it works

Comment: Just tried it. Still getting the same ^A added onto the end of the string when I cout the hint string

Comment: nevermind. somehow I compiled it to the wrong place so the version I was texting was never changing. I just tested the changed version and everything works perfectly, thanks!